# PetaPoco {"Incorrect syntax near '@0'."} CTE

Tags: sql, vb.net, petapoco

I am getting an error:

> {"Incorrect syntax near '@0'."}

When I change the @0 to an integer i.e. 100, then I get an error:

> {"Incorrect syntax near '*'."}

I am not sure what is happening. The CTE issue from what I have read shouldn't be an issue with petapoco anymore.
Any ideas?

```
 Using db = New Database("cs")
            oHistoricalTicker = db.SingleOrDefault(Of MyTicker)(";WITH CTE AS 
                                                                (
                                                                    SELECT TOP @0 (*) FROM Ticker WHERE ProductId=@1
                                                                    ORDER BY ID DESC
                                                                )  SELECT TOP (1) * FROM CTE ORDER BY ID ASC", iHistoricalTicks, TicketSymbol)

        End Using
```

Comment: Make sure your SQL run correctly with your database version. Some older ones don’t support variables with TOP. And yes as suggested by alwaysVBNET, the syntax uses the parenthesis around the top’s value.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL should be:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
 (
SELECT TOP (@0) * FROM Ticker WHERE ProductId=@1
ORDER BY ID DESC)  SELECT TOP (1) * FROM CTE ORDER BY ID ASC
```